# Generic method: Cannot convert from Tuple to T

Tags: c#, .net

I have a generic method:

```
public T Search<T>(entry entry)
{
    return (T)new Tuple<decimal, decimal>(entry.from, entry.to);

    return default(T);
}
```

I've got logic to return different results depending on the value of `T` passed in, but the compiler doesn't let me do this, instead I get this error: `"Cannot convert from Tuple to T"`

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: Why is it generic? Don't you want `public Tuple<decimal, decimal> Search(entry entry)`?

Comment: @John: No, this is just a sample code. I have many more return types. I have just included the offending code.

Comment: C# doesn't know how to magically convert a Tuple to T. Perhaps you can add some more code to demonstrate what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Thanks. Put simply I want to return a Tuple<int,int> from a generic method. Is this possible?

Comment: `public Tuple<int, int> Search(entry entry)`?

Comment: As I said from a generic method :)

Comment: Of course just change your return type: `public Tuple<int,int> Search<T>(entry entry)` and `return new Tuple<int, int>(...`

Comment: What's the point of the method being generic if you can only return `Tuple<int, int>`? I know you said generic, but the other things you've said don't marry up with it. As *I* said, you need to provide a better explanation of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: The point of generic is the Search method can for example return string. I have a switch case inside Search function so it can return for example string, int, Tuple<int, int> and so on. Therefore the simple suggestion of changing my generic method to non generic is not going to work.

Comment: @Mrug and how would C# know how to produce a `string` from a `Tuple<int, int>`?

Comment: Then its not as simple as (and I qoute) : "simply I want to return a Tuple<int,int> from a generic method". You might want to have a look at Factory-Pattern and re-consider your abstraction. Maybe you can capsule your "returns" inside a BaseClass which acts as the return type.

Comment: @John: Looks you are completely confused regarding my method and generic. Anyways please refer to Damien's answer. Would be helpful to you.

Comment: @Mrug Carry on being rude to people who try to understand your poorly written question. I'm well aware of how generics work, and I also know that trying to cast a `Tuple<decimal, decimal>` to a `string` won't work any better. As JleruOHeP said, it just transfers it to a [runtime exception](http://rextester.com/EMBB14029). If you are indeed aware of this and are handling it in code, then perhaps not ignoring my requests for a better example in your question would have gone a long way?

Comment: @John: I think you are still confused. I never said I want to convert string to Tuple. I re-iterate please read Damien's answer and particularly this line "I suspect your actual code is using branching on the type T and then conditionally trying to return something that should be compatible"

Comment: @Mrug "Put simply I want to return a Tuple<int,int> from a generic method. Is this possible?" "The point of generic is the Search method can for example return string." - If you'd said from the offset that you had branching logic to return different things then your question would have been a lot clearer. You do understand that, at least, right? Re-read your own question to work out how it's not clear that that's what you're doing.

Comment: And in future, don't ignore people's requests for additional code to clarify your question. It tends to make things a lot clearer.

Comment: @John: Do you read my comments if at all? My comment clearly mentions "The point of generic is the Search method can for example return string. I have a **switch case** inside Search function so it can return for example string, int, Tuple<int, int>" Does switch case not mean branching? Anyways you have hundred of questions for my questions but I have already got an answer. So better we stop here.

Comment: I'm just trying to give you advice for the future. Also, remember that clarification should be added as an edit to your question, not as a comment. If you have a switch case, show that in your question's code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect your actual code is using branching on the type `T` and then conditionally trying to return something that *should* be compatible.

The compiler cannot trace the internal logic and so far as it's concerned, `T` could still be **anything** when you attempt the conversion. You can force its hand with a second cast:

```
public T Search<T>(entry entry)
{
    return (T)(object)new Tuple<decimal, decimal>(entry.from, entry.to);

    return default(T);
}
```

But you better have your typing logic right or you're going to be throwing runtime errors. I personally dislike generic methods that "lie", in that they'll allow something to compile with a particular type parameter but then blow up at runtime because of type incompatibilities. I'd instead be looking to implement multiple *related* methods where you can tie the types down to only those types you really can deal with.

Comment: Brilliant stuff! Exactly what I wanted. John, could you please refer this code so you can understand how this one marries with my implementation?

Comment: This implementation just transforms a Compile time error into a Runtime error. You  want to have have those exceptions or implement a proper generic....

Comment: @JleruOHeP - which is exactly why the largest paragraph in my answer discusses this.

Comment: @Damien I'm still not sure if Mrug gets that.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, yep, just wanted to highlight type of exceptions a bit better

Answer (score 0):

To make the following work you need T to be a base class of Tuple

```
(T)new Tuple<decimal, decimal>(entry.from, entry.to);
```

Tuple is a static class not derived from anything under System namespace.

So, if you want to process data on two of your properties then create a new class with these properties and derive it from T

Or, return type be taken as

```
Tuple<decimal, decimal>
```